# How to change the json response fields to user defined fields in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json response:

```
{
"Labels": {
                     "com.prop.vendor": "Acme",
                     "com.example.license": "GPL",
                     "com.example.version": "1.0"
             }
}
```

Now I want to process these values in my java class. The problem I have is for fields like *com.example.version*, pojo is being generated using the same as data types. Like,

```
private String com.example.version
```

which gives me compile-time errors.
So, I want to create a field "String version" which points to "com.example.version"
And I have tried using  @JsonProperty and  @JsonSetter.

*Labels.java*

```
public class Labels
{
    @JsonProperty("com.example.version")
    private String version;

    @JsonProperty("com.example.vendor")
    private String vendor;

    @JsonProperty("com.example.license")
    private String license;

    public String getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version)
    {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getVendor()
    {
        return vendor;
    }

    public void setVendor(String vendor)
    {
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }

    public String getLicense()
    {
        return license;
    }

    public void setLicense(String license)
    {
        this.license = license;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [com.example.version = " + version + ", com.example.vendor = " + vendor + ", com.example.license = "
                + license + "]";
    }
}
```

But everytime I am getting this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Labels" (class com.csc.agility.adapters.service.docker.pojo.Labels), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "com.example.license", "com.example.vendor", "com.example.version"])
 at [Source: {
"Labels": {
                     "com.example.vendor": "Acme",
                     "com.example.license": "GPL",
                     "com.example.version": "1.0"
             }
}; line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.csc.agility.adapters.service.docker.pojo.Labels["Labels"])
```

How I am using it:

```
ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString =
                "{\n\"Labels\": {\n                     \"com.example.vendor\": \"Acme\",\n                     \"com.example.license\": \"GPL\",\n                     \"com.example.version\": \"1.0\"\n             }\n}";

Label label = objMap.readValue(jsonInString, Label.class);
String licence = label.getLicense();
```

Can anyone point me to the correct json annotation to use or any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried custom serializers?

Comment: you need to map "Labels" also

Comment: Yes, I am mapping it using object mapper. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure your `mapper` with

`mapper.configure(Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);` (for version 1.9)

or

`mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);` (for version 2 and above).

I have tried your json with above properties and everything works fine:

```
String data = "{\"Labels\": {\"com.example.vendor\": \"Acme\",\"com.example.license\": \"GPL\",\"com.example.version\": \"1.0\"}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
Labels labels = mapper.readValue(data, Labels.class);
System.out.println(labels);
```

Note: In Json String, I have changed `com.prop.vendor` to `com.example.vendor` to make it workable.

Comment: Minor issue: I am trying your code but I am not able to find Feature class import, can you ping me that import line and I can import the respective jar?

Comment: As already mentioned above, different configurations are required for different jackson version. Ping me your version.

Comment: Jackson-annotations 2.7.0

Comment: for this yous should use second version. and import will be `import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;`

Answer (score 0):

Have one more pojo like below and use this object instead of Labels to serialize/deserialize -

```
public class Response {
 @JsonProperty("Labels")
 private Labels labels;
 //setter 
 //getter
}
```

In your code use this -

```
Response response = objMap.readValue(jsonInString, Response.class);
String licence = response.getLabels().getLicense();
```